# Bash While Loop Variable Mishaps

Tags: arrays, bash, loops

Before you get concerned, this (hopefully) isn't another of the many threads about having variable access problems from a while loop in BASH. I looked at those and implemented the redirect method, but I'm having some issues.

Code:
    #!/bin/bash

```
rm /tmp/sched.now
rm /tmp/sched.later

NOWURL="schedNOWurl"
LATERURL="schedLATERurl"

curl -s $NOWURL --output /tmp/sched.now
curl -s $LATERURL --output /tmp/sched.later

re='^[0-9]+$'

if grep -q 'no shifts' /tmp/sched.now ; then
    nowpeople[0]="No Shifts Assigned For This Time"
    nowtime[0]="Now"
else
    while read line
    do
        if [[ ${line:0:1} =~ $re ]] ; then
            nowtime[$nowcount]=$line
            ((nowcount++))
        elif [[ ${line:0:1} == '-' ]] ; then
            nowpeople[$nowcount]=$line
            ((nowcount++))
        fi
    done < /tmp/sched.now
fi

declare -a latertime
declare -a laterpeople
if grep -q 'no shifts' /tmp/sched.later ; then
    laterpeople[0]="No Shifts Assigned For This Time"
    latertime[0]="Until 23:59"
else
    while read line
    do
        if [[ ${line:0:1} =~ $re ]] ; then
            latertime[$latercount]=$line
            ((latercount++))
        elif [[ ${line:0:1} == '-' ]] ; then
            laterpeople[$latercount]=$line
            ((latercount++))
        fi
    done < /tmp/sched.later
fi

echo ${nowpeople[@]}
echo ${nowtime[@]}
echo ${laterpeople[@]}
echo ${latertime[@]}
```

The URLs that I'm getting are HTML files. The text I'm attempting to pull in the loops looks something like this

```
11a-1:30p
- John Doe
```

with some HTML thrown above and below it. Note that these are all on their own lines.

The issue I'm facing is that the loops aren't saving all of the matches to the array. In the second loop, it should pull three entries into each array. Right now it pulls one with malformed text as follows:

```
- John Doe
1:30p-4pp
```

Notice the missing `m` in `pm` and the replaced `m` with a `p` in `pp`.
The strange thing is that if I `echo $line` before the array statement, the line is pulled from the file fine, so it sounds like it's something in the way I'm saving to the array.

Suggestions? Please let me know if you need more details.

Comment: This question is unlikely to be answered as not many people will read it all, try to write a minimal example that still presents the same problem and include input,output and expected output for a better response :)

Comment: Most everything in the post is relevant to the question though. What parts do you see as irrelevant?

Comment: It appears that the input files have DOS line endings; the carriage returns in them are treated as data by `bash` and included in the value of `$line`, and cause the type of output you are describing.